# Java:Read 3 integers and print them

Tags: java

I am having trouble with learning System.in in java so i picked up an program to learn through it but now i am stuck with the compile error.What is wrong here?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        int b = scan.nextInt();
        int c = scan.nextInt();
        Scanner.close();

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your error message. Actually, read it first.

Comment: You're​ closing it wrong, but you shouldn't be closing it since you didn't open it.

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner.close();` is not valid since **close()** method is not static, you have to use in this case the instance of the class, (***scan*** in this code) it must be

```
scan.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner.close();` should be `scan.close();`

Comment: This is the correct answer. If it is working for you. Please accept this.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Scanner.close();//Not valid
```

The above statement is not valid since close() is an instance method which should be called with respect to its class object(i.e object of Scanner class) as below.

```html
scan.close();//valid
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use Scanner.close(), a static form that doesn't exist in this class. You should  call scan.close();, the instance method.